# How to share audio files

Tags: android, audio, share

My app has a `ListView` containing several audio files. If the user long clicks a `ListViewItem` it will share the selected audio file.
I've read that in order to share something, first I have to copy the file to external storage and then share it.
I've used the following code to do so:

```
private void copyToExternalStorage(String sourceFilePath, String fileName)
{
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFilePath);
    String destinationPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myApp";
    File destinationFile = new File(destinationPath);
    if (!destinationFile.exists())
        destinationFile.mkdirs();
    destinationFile = new File(destinationPath + "/" + fileName + ".mp3");
    try
    {
        FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void share(String file, String trackName)
{
    copyToExternalStorage(file, trackName);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myApp/" +
            trackName +
            ".mp3";
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share audio"));
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
{
    share(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sounds)[i], getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tracks)
                    [i]);
    return true;
}
```

`R.array.sounds` is where I stored my audio files, and `R.array.tracks` is where I stored the track names.
The problem I'm getting is that my app does not find any files in the given `sourceFilePath`, therefore it doesn't copy nor share anything.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to copy files anywhere.  It's cleaner and safer (but more work) for your app to expose a ContentProvider that responds to a Uri that you share.  The Uri essentially becomes the locator for your file/resource that other apps can use to read it.

Have a look at the [official docs on file sharing](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) to get started.

Comment: I've read the documentation but didn't get it that well.
Basically all I need is to share an audio file located at res/raw.
I created an xml file called array that has the references to all those audio files, and I think that will make things a lot easier, but I don't know how to use it as an URI provider for my intent.

Comment: What you're trying to do is really best suited for a ContentProvider, but it's not a matter of a simple code snippet to make the whole thing work properly in the Android app ecosystem. If you do choose to go ahead with this, perhaps a different question on SO might be appropriate to help you through a rough patch.

Comment: thank you. The documentation and the ContentProvider were able to help me get through this issue. My problem is solved now.